# Running D3.js in clojure

Tags: javascript, d3.js, clojure, clojurescript

I'd like to learn how to run JavaScript through Clojure and in particular implement [this D3 graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) in Clojure.

In my attempt to implement the above graphing method I encountered [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript). However, I have been unsuccessful in its usage for the problem at hand.

Is ClojureScript the right way to go? If so, how would I implement the above D3 graph?

Comment: Basically anything that can be implemented using JavaScript can be implemented using ClojureScript. Also, you should show us your work before asking such a question here.

Comment: FYI: There is also C2, a D3-inspired data visualization library for Clojure and ClojureScript. http://keminglabs.com/c2/

Comment: Also [strokes](https://github.com/dribnet/strokes), which is intended to make it easier to use d3.js from Clojurescript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use ClojureScript. D3 is a JavaScript library, not a Java one, so to use  it you'll need to be running in a browser environment, which is what ClojureScript is for.

Then all you need to do is call the D3 api via ClojureScript's interoperability forms. Explaining how to do that at length is beyond the scope of this question.

Some resources to get you started:

Introduction to ClojureScript <-> JavaScript interoperability:
https://lambdaisland.com/episodes/clojurescript-interop

David Nolen's excellent blog series on ClojureScript: http://swannodette.github.io/2013/11/07/clojurescript-101

ClojureScript: Up and Running: [http://www.amazon.com/ClojureScript-Up-Running-Stuart-Sierra/dp/1449327435/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449327435) (disclaimer, I am one of the authors)

Comment: Currently, this project shows a concrete use of D3.js from ClojureScript:
https://github.com/scotthaleen/cljs-d3-force-direct-graph